# JPEG section placement specification

Tags: parsing, jpeg

My goal is to parse correctly any valid JPEG file. However after googling I've not discovered answer for my question: is JPEG standard documents the way of section positioning?

---

*Clarification*

In JPEG there is bulk of sections with various signatures, however in practice every JPEG image has first section APP0 and corresponding sections APP**X** after that. I wonder if there possible cases when some other section begins the file or sections mixed in random way. Would this violate standard or this behaviour is ok due to "implementation dependent" section position?

Here is an example of my JPEG file sections that illustrate what sections I'm talking about.

[image: JPEG file structure]

Comment: The "sections" are called "markers" and they can come in almost any order. They contain information vital to decode the image and metadata which can be optionally removed. It's trivial to parse them because they consist of a 2-byte marker in the form "FFxx" followed by a 2-byte length. With the length, you can skip over them or interpret their data.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ordering requirements but JPEG is flexible about where the block can occur.

There must be an SOI marker at the front.
There must be an EOI marker at the end.

Beyond that it's pretty loose.

The SOF marker must come before the SOS markers.

An SOS marker will uses Huffman tables and a quantization table These must be defined by DHT and DQT markers before they are used. However, you can have
sequences like this:

DHT
DQT
SOS
DHT
DQT
SOS
SOS

APP0 and COM markers can occur almost always.
Most JPEG file formats require an APPn marker of some type right after the SIO marker.